# Kudu Zip Deploy copies files that have not changed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sitecore, azure-web-app-service, kudu

The current setup is that we're using gulp to build our VS solution using MSBuild and an Azure DevOps release pipeline to deploy our build artifacts via the Kudu Zip Deploy API ([via PowerShell](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-a-zip-file-or-url)) to our Azure App Service.

Kudu appears to copy files that are unchanged, which appears to be causing unnecessary slowness on the target server because it causes the server to restart. Here's one example:

[image]

The contents of this file have not changed (as well as other binary files), but what probably has changed is the timestamp due to the way we're generating / regenerating some of these artifact files.

I have tried to see if [Kudu can be configured](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#repository-and-deployment-related-settings) to ignore timestamps, but there doesn't seem to be an option for it, and it might also not be a good solution. According to the [Kudu zip deploy docs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-a-zip-file-or-url):

> Efficient file copy: Files will only be copied if their timestamps don't match what is already deployed. Generating a zip using a build process that caches outputs can result in faster deployments.

Other ideas include it being a misconfiguration in the solution / file settings, or an issue with the way we're building via gulp. Any ideas on how I can prevent these unchanged files from being copied?

Comment: The quickest and most natural way to detect unchanged is the timestamp.  Reading and tracking the content hash would be slow if were to be done for all files unless you have better suggestion.   Is there a workaround on gulp to not touch the timestamp if unchanged?

Comment: @SuwatCh I believe the reason why is because the gulp script builds the solution rather than each individual project, which causes each binary to have a new timestamp. The first step would likely be to build each project instead. But I wonder if that would even help. On a hosted VS2017 build agent in Azure DevOps, I can't see it persisting binaries across multiple builds.